# SSH authentication via SSH-key not working, not even on same machine, keeps asking for password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Before resolving the issue that I can't connect from my client to remote using publickey authentification, I thought I should try logging in from my remote account onto that same remote account just to make sure that ssh is set up correctly on remote. Password authentification works fine in any case. Here are the steps I have tried on the remote, where `sshd` is running:

```
rm -rf ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen
```

I have tried multiple key types with various bit lengths, the result was insensitive to that.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Manual copy and paste of the public key into `authorized_keys` didn't affect the outcome. I have tried setting the permissions to the folder `.ssh` to 700 and of `.ssh/authorized_keys` to 600, which also didn't seem to have any notable effect.

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

And here's the complete output of trying to `ssh` from the remote onto the remote while being connected from my client via `ssh` using password authentication, in this case with an `rsa` key:

```
[user@remote ~]$ ssh -v -i .ssh/id_key remote
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_key type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to remote:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXX
debug1: Host 'remote' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:131179)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:131179)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/id_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@remote's password:
```

**How can I make the ssh service accept the public key?**

Thank you very much, you are my last resort after hours of reading through manuals and webpages. Please let me know if you need to see some options of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I thought it is probably not necessary to paste it here because the publickey authentication is obviously enabled.

Comment: Run `sshd` on the server side in debug mode, by issuing `$(which sshd) -d -d -d -p 22222` and try to connect to that port (22222) by SSH. Then add the server's debug output (which should contain the reason why the key was not accepted) to the question.

Comment: @Lacek Thanks! This is so weird: when running `sshd` on port 22222 and connecting to that port, the key is accepted. No Port is specified in `/etc/sshd_config`, so it should default to 22. But when connecting to that port the key is not accepted. Any ideas?